# How to request customs for revaluation of Customs Duty on the prize received to India from US in a competition

Tags: united-states, taxes, india, gst, customs

I got a prize from website from US as I was winner in the event. Parcel was posted to **India**  through **USPS** its a Honor Band 3 which costs around 50 USD in US and 2800 INR in India.
Today I received the parcel to my address and to my surprise customs has charged me 1717 INR(which includes IGST as 28% and basic custom duty 10% ie.., total 38% ) as customs charge which is ridiculously high.One of my friend too got the same prize but wasn't charged anything.

Is there any way to request for reassessment of the charges?

Has anyone faced similar case if yes how did you solve the problem?

What happens to the parcel if I refuse to pay the charges.Will it be sent back to the sender or will it be struck in customs?

Please provide me any additional information to solve the issue.

Image of the charges:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iAmF.jpg

Comment: Not only is the overall rate 42.1% (because the 28% rate is applied *after* the 10% + 1% rates), but it is applied to a value of 4080, because the currency conversion rate used is much higher than you used, resulting in a 61% rate on the value you stated.

Comment: Haven't Noticed that, then it is too high than what I was thinking earlier.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to request for reassessment of the charges?

Generally the best course in such situation is not to take the delivery and dispute the percentage of customs duty applied.

Refer to [Section 27 of the Customs Act, 1962](http://www.cbec.gov.in/htdocs-cbec/customs/cs-act/cs-act-ch5) for procedure for filing refunds. Related [FAQ on Customs](http://accmumbai.gov.in/aircargo/import/faq.html)